How to determine if photoshopped - ela all red, string data says photoshopped, inconsistencies, bluriness
Can anyone tell me if my photos are being photoshopped. I have good reason to believe they are.  Normal photos do not have the photoshopped adobe txt in the string data as the other ones do and the ela is NOT all red.  It is white or non existent.  Does this mean these are photos have been tampered with?  I can’t tell as it says just stating the photoshopped and adobe line in string text doesn’t mean it has been altered but only some have it, on the same phone.
